# Why value is not updating in template in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

i have an `angular` `component` in which i have `onInit` function and in that i am doing this

```
  pastAppts: any = [];
  presentAppt: any = [];

  this.dataService.getData().subscribe(obj => {
  // console.log('in upcoming subscruber : ', obj);
  if (obj.data.type === 'passdata' && obj.data.key === 'customer-appointments' && obj.data.data) {
    this.userAppointments = obj.data.data.length > 0 ? obj.data.data : [];
    console.log('appointments : ', this.userAppointments);
    this.userAppointments = this.userAppointments.sort(function (a, b) {
      return new Date(b.startDateTime).getTime() - new Date(a.startDateTime).getTime();
    });
    this.pastAppts = this.userAppointments.filter(i => i.start && new Date(i.start).getDate() < new Date().getDate());
    this.presentAppt = this.userAppointments.filter(i => i.start && new Date(i.start).getDate() >= new Date().getDate());
    console.log(this.pastAppts.length, this.presentAppt.length);
  }
});
```

`component.html`

```
<div class="past-appointment-section" *ngIf="pastAppts.length > 0">
<div class="ui-g-12 p-zero plr-5 mt-2">
  <p class="appointment-heading text-center">Past Appointments</p>
</div>
<div>
  <div *ngFor="let appointment of pastAppts | slice:0:2">
    <app-appointment-card [appointment]="appointment" [isPast]="true"></app-appointment-card>
  </div>
</div>
```

Problem is that in my componet.ts at this line `console.log(this.pastAppts.length, this.presentAppt.length);` i am getting lengths `11,0` it means `pastAppts` have length of `11` but in template my value is not updating and that html is not rendering. Why it is not updating value in template?

Comment: Try this this.pastAppts = [...this.userAppointments.filter(i => i.start && new Date(i.start).getDate() < new Date().getDate())];

Comment: doesn't work. The issue is that  array length is not updating in template.

Comment: is pastAppts a global var or is declared in onInit()?

Comment: Be careful, getDate() will not return the date. It returns you the day as number (number 1-31). Also, it is possible that ngFor can't track the changes in your items. Then you can use a trackBy function in your ngFor: https://netbasal.com/angular-2-improve-performance-with-trackby-cc147b5104e5

Comment: @OAH it is global variable.

Comment: make sure that you have ```import 'zone.js/dist/zone';``` in polyfills.ts

Comment: I have this in my polyfils.ts